# Optimize a SQL query with INDEX

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple query

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table FORCE INDEX (col2)
WHERE col2 IN ('there', 'are, 'around', 'six', 'values', 'here')
```

with index `col2` for col2. My `table` has around 10 millions row. I used `FORCE INDEX` here because there are other indices in my table and MySQL uses one of other indices instead of index `col2`. The other index is very slow for this query.

List of all indices in my table:

```
INDEX col2 (col2)
UNIQUE INDEX ind1 (col1, col2)
INDEX ind2 (col1, col2)
INDEX ind3 (col2, col1)
```

This query (with `FORCE INDEX`) is not slow (takes 6 seconds on AWS RDS free tier) but there is a need to make it as fast as possible. Is there any thing else I could do to speed up this query?

Comment: Unless the query optimizer is getting it wrong, you should not force an index. There are times when using an index is slower.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: The query is straightforward. MySQL should be able to figure out the right index. What are the other indexes, what is the schema, and what is the real query?

Comment: I could imagine that the default collation of the constants and in the table is different, preventing the use of the index on `col2`.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: What is index `col2`?  None of the three indices you do have bear this name.

Comment: edited the post

Comment: *List of all indices in my table* You may remove `ind2` and `col2` freely (they're excess) and force `ind3` usage.

Comment: Which index is the query optimizer picking?

Comment: @TommyDo Please consider posting from your AWS RDS site, TEXT results of A) EXPLAIN SELECT (your query); and B) SHOW INDEX FROM table; for analysis. Is there a good reason you do not have a PRIMARY KEY index?

Comment: How many items are in the real `IN` list?

Comment: Which index did it use when you left out the `FORCE`?  (That may be a big clue of what is going 'wrong'.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should try *not* forcing the index on `col2`, and instead just look at the explain plan.  It is likely that a single column index on `col2` would be used here.  However, you can try adding the following composite covering index on your table:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (col2, col1, col3, col4);
```

This index would cover the `WHERE` clause, and also includes the other columns which appear in the `SELECT` clause.  If it chooses, MySQL could use this index to completely cover the entire query without needing to seek back to the clustered index (i.e. the original table).

Comment: I tried omitting FORCE INDEX but the query becomes very slow (MySQL uses another index). I don't have the index you state here. Do you think this index can potentially be faster than the index `col2`?

Comment: I'm curious what this other index is.  The index I suggest above should be the "best" option for you, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX col2 (col2)
UNIQUE INDEX ind1 (col1, col2)
INDEX ind2 (col1, col2)
INDEX ind3 (col2, col1)
```

Some of these indexes are redundant. MySQL can use `(col2, col1)` for searches on `col2` as well as searches on both `col2` and `col1`. And `ind2` is fully redundant with `ind1`.

The redundancy might be confusing the optimizer.

To cover all combinations of `col1` and `col2`, as well as enforce uniqueness, you only need...

```
INDEX col2 (col2)
UNIQUE INDEX ind1 (col1, col2)
```

Removing the redundant indexes will speed up inserts and save space.

See [8.3.6 Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

---

The [query planner makes its guesses based on table statistics](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/index-statistics.html). Sometimes those statistics are out of date. Try running [`analyze table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) to update them.